# How to provision predefined imagerenditions to all site collections inside a web application?

Tags: feature, image-rendition

I am using sp 2013. I have followed [this](http://www.eliostruyf.com/provision-image-renditions-to-your-sharepoint-2013-site/) tutorial. But I am struggling with the scopes. I would like to implement my module (predefined image rendition xml file) to all site collections inside web application A.

I have now a module and the image renditions xml file. Now I need to create a feature. Do I need to make the feature web application scoped and set it to automatic start? Or scope site collecion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would scope the feature for site collections and activate it (with powershell) in all sites.

If you want it in new site collections you could staple it to a site template or use an [event receiver](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2010/10/07/how-to-attach-an-event-receiver-to-the-web-added-event-and-for-what-purpose/).